# How to localize Microsoft Bot Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, botframework

I am creating a bot application using `Microsoft Bot Framework` and want to localize the bot with multiple languages. I have created resource files but I don't know how to proceed with setting the culture. I know about `Localizing MVC Web Application` but I am not getting how do I do this for the `Dialogs` in `Bot Application`.

Comment: Is this relevant to your requirement? https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/localization/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941878/how-to-set-up-localization-for-botframework-node-bot

Comment: Thanks @Souvik But this for NodeJs right is there anything as such for dot.net as my application is dot net

Comment: Ok check this out- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers

Comment: Have you looked at the https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html#localizingSection ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Resources.resx file for your default language. From there you can create another resx for other languages such as Resources.fr.resx for french. Then change the language in your c# app using something like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
Console.WriteLine(Properties.Resources.Hello);
```

To switch back to default set the culture to anything you haven't accounted for. So if you set culture to "en-EN" it will not find anything because we only have Resources.resx and Resources.fr.resx, so it will return to default (Resources.resx) which could be english, german, or anything else.